# Derive a Parent attribute as True if all of its Child attributes are True

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Parent"

    parent_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    complete = Column(Boolean)

    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Child"

    child_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer,
                         ForeignKey('Parent.parent_id'))
    complete = Column(Boolean)

    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children",
                            foreign_keys=[parent_id])
```

I want to take the tables above and for the parent complete boolean be calculated as True if all the Child complete values are True, and False if any of the Child complete values are false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to declare `completed` as real column in the "Parent" table, you just need to create a `@hybrid_property` in the `Parent` object that

- looks for incomplete child objects, and
- returns `False` if it finds one or more.

```py
class Parent(Base):
    # …
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

    @hybrid_property
    def completed(self):
        if self.children:
            return not bool([c for c in self.children if not c.completed])
        else:
            return False  # parent has no children
```